# trigger tab press key event on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a request where on page load I should trigger the tab press keyboard event. I tried below example but it does not work.

My requirement is to set focus on a element in parent html page on page load, but I do not have access to the source code of this parent page. My html page is part of the parent as a frame. So on load of my page (parent is already loaded) I want to trigger the tab press key event to set the focus on the element from parent.

Note : This element is the first element in the parent page and hence on first tab the focus shifts to this. I cannot edit the parent page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#input1").focus();
             var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
             press.which = 9;
             $("#input1").trigger(press);
         });
         
         
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="text" name="myInput1" id="input1" />
      <input type="text" name="myInput2" id="input2" />
      <input type="text" name="myInput3" id="input3" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `1` ?? it can't be an `id` also `$("1")` is wrong, `$('#id')` is correct / see your post updated.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. My bad it was type, I corrected the code. But the problem is tab key event is not triggered

Comment: Are you using `ifram` ? , i don't  understand what you mean of `parent html page`

Comment: yes, it is iframe. My code is part of iframe

Comment: You can't control parent `html` from `iframe`.

Comment: so we dont have any workaround for that ? cant we refer to the parent page some how ?

Comment: `but I do not have access to the source code` if you say so, the answer is `NO` but test this `window.parent.document.getElementById('#input1');` alert it, see it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

This `$("1")` won't work. You have to grab the element by class `$(".1")` or id `$("#1")`. In your case it would be `$("#1")`.

Comment: Probably due to [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

To find in the parent of the iFrame use:

```
$('#parentPrice', window.parent.document).focus();
```

The second parameter for the $() wrapper is the context in which to search. This defaults to document.